# encrypting a file using shift

Tags: python, file

Not sure what im doing wrong here? the program asks for file name and reads the file but when it come to printing the encoded message it comes up blank. What am I missing, as if I change the phrase to just normal raw_input("enter message") the code will work, but this is not reading from the txt file.

```
letters = "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
cshift = int(input("Enter a number: "))
phrase = open(raw_input("file name: "), 'r')
newPhrase = ""
for l in phrase:
   if l in letters:
        pos = letters.index(l) + cshift
        if pos > 25:
            pos = pos-26
        newPhrase += letters[pos]

else:
    newPhrase += " "
print(newPhrase)
```

Comment: `phrase` is a file object. You're not reading any data from it.

Comment: @TomZych Yes he is, he's enumerating over it. Unfortunately, enumerating over the file handle will give him the lines of the file, not the characters of the file.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Whoops, you're right. But `l` will be a line and OP is treating it like a character.

Comment: Edits that pass in the night :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the for-loop on this line:

```
for l in phrase:
```

will return complete lines, not individual characters.

As such you will have to loop through individual characters from those lines as well, or read the file binary, or use functions on the file object that will read one character at a time.

You could simply do this:

```
for line in phrase:
    for l in line:
        ... rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The `open` function does not return a string, but a handle to the opened file from which strings can be read.  You should search for information on how to read a file into a string in Python and then try it in a REPL to make sure it returns a string and not something else.

Comment: He *is* reading the lines of the file, that's not the problem. Well, the problem isn't that he isn't reading the file, the problem is that he's reading the *lines* of the file.

Comment: There are other ways to do this, but I think the OP should set the variable named `phrase` to a string containing the phrase, not a file handle.  Then the code will work and that variable will have a reasonable name.

Comment: I agree with that. Clearer naming would avoid future confusion.